# c# Animation via sequence of pictures

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I made animation in Windows Forms via c#. I have a bitmap inside a code which updates frequently. After each update pictureBox draws this bitmap. But if I work with big bitmap (e.g 1000 height), it draws really slow and my animation moves slow too.

How can I avoid this lag? Ofc I can reduce frames for my animation, but I dont want to do that. May be I could use some 2D rendering libraries to draw that image? I'm looking for any possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a video format, like .wmv or .mpeg? You can include an instance of media player inside a windows form.

Or are you generating the bitmaps on the fly?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating animation frames on the fly. My program animates some algorithm which works with input data.

Comment: Are you restricted to using Winforms? Because I believe WPF would be more fitting for your task.

Comment: Is it possible to make in WPF without a lot of code refactor? May be with help of ElementHost?

Comment: There are things you can do to speed it up, but it's not an efficient way to do animations.